# Struggling with OkHttp interceptors

Tags: java, json, okhttp

I need to overrwrite the content-type header that OkHttp sets by default. I've tried many things and this is the closest i've gotten to having it work. From what I've found I need to use interceptors but just really struggling to learn them. My expected behavior is for my API POST request to go through, but it doesn't because the content-type isn't being properly set and I get a 415 Unsupported Media Type. I'm using the ITGlue API.

```java
public class APIHandler {
     public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    public class DefaultContentTypeInterceptor implements Interceptor {

        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain)
                throws IOException {

            Request originalRequest = chain.request();
            Request requestWithUserAgent = originalRequest
                    .newBuilder()
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json")
                    .build();

            return chain.proceed(requestWithUserAgent);
        }
    }
    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new DefaultContentTypeInterceptor()).build();


    public void run(String input) throws Exception {
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.Companion.create("{\"data\": {\n" +
                "  \"type\": \"attachments\",\n" +
                "  \"attributes\": {\n" +
                "    \"attachment\": {\n" +
                "      \"content\": \""+input+"\",\n" +
                "      \"file_name\": \"test.png\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "}", JSON);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.itglue.com/configurations/33880577/relationships/attachments")

                .header("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json")
                .addHeader("x-api-key", "ITG.baaa9df19a1ec7d2c9159d2c18eef763.TG9j_uj3kiDHIjZ4TMPz_IrfIBh9jLDvdEKc9UiwGNmVz6jnyYwFqrDgiA4ZaJB9")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        System.out.println(requestBody.toString());

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: Have you tried registering a network interceptor instead ? https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/#network-interceptors

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your `RequestBody` with the right media type in the first place?

```
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create("{...}", MediaType.get("application/vnd.api+json")));
```